# Allocation of Function Literals in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a class that represents sales orders:

`class SalesOrder(val f01:String, val f02:Int, ..., f50:Date)`

The `fXX` fields are of various types. I am faced with the problem of creating an audit trail of my orders. Given two instances of the class, I have to determine which fields have changed. I have come up with the following:

```
class SalesOrder(val f01:String, val f02:Int, ..., val f50:Date){

  def auditDifferences(that:SalesOrder): List[String] = {

    def diff[A](fieldName:String, getField: SalesOrder => A) =
      if(getField(this) != getField(that)) Some(fieldName) else None

    val diffList = diff("f01", _.f01) :: diff("f02", _.f02) :: ...
                :: diff("f50", _.f50) :: Nil

    diffList.flatten
  }    
}
```

I was wondering what the compiler does with all the `_.fXX` functions: are they instanced just once (statically), and can be shared by all instances of my class, or will they be instanced every time I create an instance of my class?

My worry is that, since I will use a lot of SalesOrder instances, it may create a lot of garbage. Should I use a different approach?

Comment: You could also worry about creating `Some` objects or storing fields changes in `List` versus arrays. Or how you will reconstruct the audit trail if you have to call `diff` `n-1` times for `n` sales order. The way you wrote right now would leave opportunities for optimization if you run into performance problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One clean way of solving this problem would be to use the standard library's [`Ordering` type class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering). For example:

```
class SalesOrder(val f01: String, val f02: Int, val f03: Char) {
  def diff(that: SalesOrder) = SalesOrder.fieldOrderings.collect {
    case (name, ord) if !ord.equiv(this, that) => name
  }
}

object SalesOrder {
  val fieldOrderings: List[(String, Ordering[SalesOrder])] = List(
    "f01" -> Ordering.by(_.f01),
    "f02" -> Ordering.by(_.f02),
    "f03" -> Ordering.by(_.f03)
  )
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val orderA = new SalesOrder("a", 1, 'a')
orderA: SalesOrder = SalesOrder@5827384f

scala> val orderB = new SalesOrder("b", 1, 'b')
orderB: SalesOrder = SalesOrder@3bf2e1c7

scala> orderA diff orderB
res0: List[String] = List(f01, f03)
```

You almost certainly don't need to worry about the perfomance of your original formulation, but this version is (arguably) nicer for unrelated reasons.

Comment: I am curious about the "unrelated reasons" :-) Is using `Ordering` better than comparing for inequality using `!=` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that creates 50 short lived functions. I don't think you should be worried unless you have manifest evidence that that causes a performance problem in your case.

But I would define a method that transforms `SalesOrder` into a `Map[String, Any]`, then you would just have

```
trait SalesOrder {
  def fields: Map[String, Any]
}
def diff(a: SalesOrder, b: SalesOrder): Iterable[String] = {
  val af = a.fields
  val bf = b.fields 
  af.collect { case (key, value) if bf(key) != value => key }
}
```

If the field names are indeed just incremental numbers, you could simplify

```
trait SalesOrder {
  def fields: Iterable[Any]
}
def diff(a: SalesOrder, b: SalesOrder): Iterable[String] =
  (a.fields zip b.fields).zipWithIndex.collect { 
    case ((av, bv), idx) if av != bv => f"f${idx + 1}%02d"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. The fields have real names. fXX was just a simplification. While using a `Map[String, Any]` solves the allocation problem, I think it has the drawback of losing type safety: I cannot ensure that the values I am assigning to them are of the right type. I think I would rather have a companion object where I place all these functions.

Comment: The map would be just auxiliary, not replacing your regular getter methods. For the equals operation, it doesn't matter whether `Any` comes out of the map or not. Basically, what I'm saying is that if you collect all field values first into some sequence, then you can compare them with just one closure instead of 50 closures.